# Passing value from input field to selectbox option

Tags: javascript

Selectbox used for city name in application form

```
<select id="city" class="custom-select form-control" name="jobman-field-7[]">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="Other">Other Please Specify</option>
    <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
    <option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
    <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
</select>
```

Input field shows when 'OTHER' selected from a Selectbox above

```
<div class="form-group" id="other-city">
    <label>Enter your city here</label>
    <input name="other-city" value="" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Javascript to toggle the fields

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields();
    $("#city").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });
});

function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#city").val() == 'Other') {
        $("#other-city").show();
    } else {
        $("#other-city").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to send the value of input field to selectbox so I could display in the same area in backend/admin section where we have  a column of CITY when other is selected

Answer (score 0):

Here your approach doesn't look meaningful I guess. You have options in your select box being retrieved from DB, appending user input as an option does not make your new data reflected in DB. Better try to trigger an ajax call to insert data into city column in your DB table when the form is submitted. This could be one way to solve your requirement so next time when a user visits page, the new result will be retrieved and shown in the select box again.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I havent added the saving to db part; Hope u can handle that;
I have focused on passing value from input box to dropdown;

Please see if this helps you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="city-form" onsubmit="return addCitytoDropDown()" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group" id="other-city">
    <label>Enter your city here</label>
    <input name="other-city" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBox">
  </div>
</form>

<select id="city" class="custom-select form-control" name="jobman-field-7[]">
  <option value="PickCity" selected>Pick a City</option>
  <option value="Other">Other Please Specify</option>
  <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
  <option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
  <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function addCitytoDropDown(){
    var x = document.getElementById("city");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var newCity = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;
    option.text = newCity;
    option.selected = true;
    x.add(option);
    return false;
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Raj, but this isn't working as you can see it in fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SDHNY/#update&togetherjs=lj82ujMj5V

Comment: Is there a way to remove the ADD CITY button as these will be in a jop application form so may be when entered city name in input field the value passed to selectbox

Comment: Sorry there's the fiddle new link:

Comment: I have updated my answer. Note: It wont work in fiddle; copy it to a html file and run in browser. let me if it helps. if it meets your requirement, please choose it as right answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

//I NEED SOMETHING LIKE THIS BUT OTHER and the NEW CITY get selected Can we only select one city when added?

```
<select multiple id="city">
<option value="PickCity"></option>
<option value="Other">Other Please Specify</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="other-city">

$().ready(function() {
 $('#other-city').change(function() {
 var option = new Option($('#other-city').val(), "value");
 $('#city option:selected').append(option);
});
});
```